# What lens do I need?

Tags: lens, optics, color-management

I am looking to mimic the below photos to the best of my ability. Hue, the softness of the photo, cool toned, range of view, etc. I have a Sony a7III. I understand editing is done to the photo after the fact, but would like to use the best lens possible to give me a solid starting point.
I have tried a sigma 18-50mm 1:2.8 but find the colors to be way too warm.

What lens would you recommend I try?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to follow up on Philip's answer, I think you should take a look at the "Creative Style" setting in your camera.

https://helpguide.sony.net/ilc/1720/v1/en/contents/TP0001653152.html

Note what it says at the bottom of that page:

- [Creative Style] is fixed to [Standard] in the following situations:

  - [Intelligent Auto]
  - [Scene Selection]
  - [Picture Effect] is set to other than [Off].
  - [Picture Profile] is set to other than [Off].

So you need to understand which mode the camera is in. Maybe "P (Program Auto)" mode is the best option for you.

Answer (score 8):

**Lenses do not affect colour balance to any significant degree** - they are designed to be as neutral as possible. If the colours are too warm, reduce the colour temperature in your camera (or in post-processing); this will be orders of magnitude more significant than any changes in the colour temperature of the picture due to the lens.

If you are finding that colour balance does vary with lens and/or you cannot change the colour balance in camera, this will be due to actions your *camera* is taking, not due to the differences in the lens; it is most likely set to auto white balance and/or some fixed preset where the camera is attempting to choose the "correct" white balance. If you put your camera to a fixed white balance, you will find that the colour balance does not vary significantly with different lenses.

Therefore to answer your question as asked: you should use your current lens.

Comment: I can't edit the white balance within my camera -- it does not allow me to click that option in the menu. I am renting lenses to find what best suits my needs so I would prefer to find the right lens.

Comment: Lenses do not affect white balance to any significant degree; they are designed (as much as is possible) to be entirely neutral.

Comment: I shot with a sigma 35mm f.1.4 and it was significantly less warm than my current 18-50 f.1.28.

Comment: I would love to find out what camera this woman uses I'm not well versed in photography but I'm being tasked and would love to learn so I am trying to find the proper starting point to accomplish photos similar to this https://www.southofsouthernphotographer.com/#/food/

Comment: @DREW your issue seems to be more of not being able to adjust the white balance (in camera or in post), so perhaps you can check out some question related to that?

Comment: Again, your BEST option is to adjust the white balance. It might be blocked because you are using some automatic preset that gives you an automatic white balance. Try switching to manual and the white balance would also be unblocked. The BEST solid starting point is to know your camera.

Comment: @DREW The difference when you used each lens was not due to differences between the two lenses, it was almost certainly due to the differences between the two scenes you photographed and the difference between the light illuminating each at the time. Even under the same lighting, if you place objects of different colors in a scene, it can affect where the camera will automatically place the white balance.

Comment: What Rafael and Michael said; I've rewritten the answer a bit to include some of this information.